# difference between "confer" upon & "confers" upon

Tags: grammaticality

In an example like:

Aristotle University upon recommendation from College of Nursing and by authority of the Board of Governors of Aristotle University hereby "confer" upon Mr. John Williams the Bachelors of Science in Nursing Degree.

Please suggest if ("confer" upon) as used above is right or it is better to use ("confers" upon)

Comment: If you see the University as an indivisible whole (as Americans typically do), then "*confers* upon" is correct. If you see a university as a collection of individuals (as Brits typically do), then "*confer* upon" is correct. Bottom line: either is fine, which will pass better depends on the dialect of your readers.

Comment: @Dan Brown While I'm (almost) all for logical concord, I think 'The University ... confer' sounds almost mixed-register. I'd prefer 'The Academic Bigwigs of A U ... confer' (or equivalent).

Comment: @DanBron - I'm rather puzzled by your assertion that the British  see a university as a collection of individuals rather than as an institution. I'm not aware that either Americans or Brits take such a nationality-based view. What are the grounds for your perception?

Comment: @edwin I was trying to say the "University as a unit" takes the *-s* form, and the "University = a collection of individuals" takes the no-S form. In the US, we would say "NYU conferS upon John Smith..."

Comment: @Dan Bron It's the psycholinguistics I'm querying, as Erik mentions. 'The University are divided over ...' sounds very strange to me – I'd expect some fine structure – whereas 'The jury are divided over ...' makes perfect sense. There are far more layers 'in a University'.

Comment: @Erik, My grounds for saying *anything* about BrE are shaky indeed, my personal exposure being limited to Monty Python, Douglas Adams, Terry Pratchett, and a rather motley assortment of colleagues and friends in the UK. That said, I've noticed this latter group tend to say "<Company> *are*", where I would unquestionably say "<Company> *is*". When I hear "J.P. Morgan *are* being scrutinized after this latest scandal", it  sounds to me like the speaker envisions JPM as an collection of people, not a holistic company. Unfortunately I don't know the term for this difference, so I can't google it.

Comment: @edwin, Ah, here's someone explaining the difference better than I ever could: http://alt-usage-english.org/groupnames.html

Comment: @Dan Bron Good find. Nice. Can I emphasise '**A number** of other nouns, such as 'team' and 'committee', behave [are treated] in the same way as 'government'.' I don't think _anyone_ would say 'the nunnery were divided'; 'the kindergarten were taken to the seaside'. Metonymy is idiosyncratic: ?/*'The jug boiled'.

Comment: @Edwin, But how about a University? Would "Oxford University confer upon Mr. Edwin Ashworth the degree of..." sound fine or weird to you? Does it change if we name a specific department, as in "The English Department at Oxford confer upon ..." work?

Comment: I'd be far happier with the latter, where there's a genus - species rather than say an order - species relationship. There seem to be far fewer relevant internet examples for 'University confer' than for 'University confers', as I'd expect there to be. _Some of these_ seem headlinese ('Jodhpur university confer doctorate on Big B'); '“I’m honored to be appointed to this position and look forward to serving the students, faculty and staff of the university,” Confer says' is a fun false positive, due to (2009) Missouri S&T student Laura Confer.

Comment: ... If you insist on being parochial, there are 6 Google hits for "Oxford University confer" (of which I think 1 is neither non-BrE nor the subjunctive) but 125 000 for "Oxford University confers". I'm not going to filter the later for false positives.

Answer (score 1):

The query sentence is sloppily composed, and reflects poorly on the institution that generated it. Much better would be this:

> Aristotle University, upon recommendation from **the** [*or* **its**] College of **Nursing,** and by authority of its Board of Governors, hereby **confers** upon Mr. John Williams the **degree of Bachelor** of Science in Nursing.

(Boldface indicates changed text and/or any associated punctuation.)

In my opinion, there needs to be a very good reason to treat *university* as a plural noun. No such reason is apparent here, as the degree is being awarded *by the institution,* not by individual members of its staff.

Comment: The institution cannot accept recommendations (or listen to music, watch TV, walk the dog ...). I'd say that the subject needs expanding here, as I agree that 'The University confer' sounds at best incongruous.